# To check Internet connection continuously using Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, background-process, internet-connection

I am using Broadcast Receiver to run a background process when Internet connection is available . I'm specifying "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" in intent filter's action. My problem is that it is executed only once when my internet connection state is changed ,  whereas i want to run my background process whenever my internet connection is available . So to achieve this , what should i provide inside intent filter ?

Comment: Unless you post code, nobody can help you. Edit your question and add relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `BroadcastReceiver` to detect changes in connectivity. If you now have connectivity, start a `Service`. The `Service` can run until the connectivity state has changed, at which point you can stop it.